# Generators in Typescript `for...of` loop

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get Typescript to compile the following generator-loop correctly, which in a modern browser works as expected:

```
/** Should print "x= 1 y= 2" **/
function* gen() { yield [1, 2] }
for (const [x, y] of gen()) { console.log("x=", x, "y=", y) }
```

But after running it through Typescript it fails.  Putting the above into [the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) illustrates the failure, namely that the `for-of` is converted to an array iteration loop but the generator is returning an object.

It seems Typescript is broken, and if so is this a known issue?  I didn't see it on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript.

What's the best workaround?  Using `Array.from` on the generator function strikes me as the most coherent?

Comment: If you want typescript to leave your code as is, you can specify es6 as a target in compiler options: _"target": "es6"_

Comment: @AlekseyL. The objective is ES3 compatibility for the Knockout.js library.

Comment: Running your example on the playground actually results in an error: "Type 'IterableIterator<number[]>' is not an array type or a string type." See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#targeting-es5-and-es3

Comment: @str . Interesting. I don't get that error in Chrome 63.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, the issue is that the `for of` loop is being transpiled to a simple array loop in es5/es3 target.

If you add `"downlevelIteration": true` to your `tsconfig.json`, it should work, and the resulting code will look completely different.

Do notice, that if you have other `for of` loops iterating over plain arrays, downlevel iteration will incur a small performance hit. ([Which is why downlevel iteration is hidden behind a flag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/04/10/announcing-typescript-2-3-rc/)).

Also, I would read [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/06/30/typescript-2-3-downlevel-iteration-for-es3-es5), especially the part about 'Reducing Code Size with --importHelpers and tslib'.